# The width of a power set graph and its orientations

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

Let $G(\mathcal{P}(n),E)$ be the undirected graph for the power set of $[n]$ elements under the inclusion relation (i.e. a poset). The width of this poset - which is defined as the size of the maximum antichain- is $k_1=\binom{n}{n/2}$( per Sperner's theorem when $n$ is even).

Let $H(\mathcal{P}(n),\hat{E})$ be a bipolar orientation of $G$. $H$ defines a poset with width $k_2$. Is it always the case that $k_1\geq k_2$? Because from trail and error and experimenting on $[3]$ it seems that's the case. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding something, but doesn't Sperner's theorem mean that the $k_1$ is the size of the largest independent set in $G$?  Wouldn't that then imply your result?

Comment: @TylerSeacrest Yes. but since I'm not mathematician I thought maybe there is a known result/reference for this. My proof is simple: assume $k_2=k_1+1$ then there is a vertex $v_0$ whose not in the layer (i.e. the largest independent set $\theta$) since its bipolar there must be a path from $v_0$ to the sink or source traversing over one element in $\theta$ therefore $k_2$ cannot be larger than $k_1$.

Comment: Personally, I'm not really an expert on posets, so I don't have great reference for you.  I will say for me translating this problem into graph theoretic terms (i.e. anti-chains are independent sets, H is the same as G except oriented and with added edges) makes the problem a lot clearer to me, since it then follows from the fact you can't increase the size of an independent set by adding edges.  If you're curious, you can research [comparability graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth's_theorem#Perfection_of_comparability_graphs).